# Community page based off of template page not showing title correctly in LinkedIn

Tags: community, metadata, linkedin, community-template

I cannot seem to get the correct Community page title to display when sharing the URL on a LinkedIn post. 
[image: Page Properties]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the title and description to each individual page, on the builder you must to go to the page properties and then modify title and description in the SEO section, if you want to do even better, you can also edit the page meta tag to use open graph.

One thing to keep in mind, I think that in scratch org those titles and descriptions are not generated.

Comment: Please provide more details.  I have the Title and SEO set on page property.  I tried setting the Metatag data to the following but it isn't changing the title displayed when posting a LinkedIn article.  



<meta property="og:title" content="Demand will be higher than anticipated for biopharmaceutical manufacturing talent!" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Demand will be higher than anticipated for biopharmaceutical manufacturing talent!" />

Comment: I recreated the Community page from scratch and it is still displaying an incorrect title when posting in LinkedIn.  It is a different page title.  Not sure where it is pulling page titles from.

Comment: that's what I mentioned, they are not generated in scratch org and sandbox correctly, https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/advanced-seo-lightning-communities.html , Salesforce as a single page app generates static html for the bots, but is not generated if you are not on prod, I you want to test it, I suggest add those Open Graph properties to the head markup on the community(test the shar to see if it works and then remove it)

Comment: I am in my production org.  When I said scratch I just meant that I recreated the page in production.  I am not working in a scratch org.

Comment: I have been looking at the LinkedIn inspector tool to see what metatags it is successfully retrieving.  It doesn't appear to be picking up anything I put in the Page Properties or the Metatags section.  

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/niimbl.force.com%2Fs%2Fdemand-for-biopharma-workforce-talent2%2F

Comment: Weird, you are doing in the right way, did you publish those changes?

Comment: I published them.  I just did a SEO/Content Snapshot/Refresh Snapshot and that has made it work!!!  I guess the old data was cached & no matter what I did it wouldn't pick the new information up.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that, see you Michele